# How do I inner join in the same table and join foreign keys with different titles?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Example data:

```
id_num: 1, 2, 3, 4

name: bob, lee, john, gary
```

I'm trying to match the corresponding data in the same table with the names.

```
 SELECT e.ID_NUM as "ID NUMBER", 
 b.NAME as "Name"
 FROM EMPLOYEE E
 JOIN EMPLOYEE B on E.ID_NUM = B.NAME
```

I get an "**invalid number**" error.

My second question is, how do I join foreign keys with different names but same values in two2 different tables?

```
table: example1
id_num: 1, 2, 3, 4

table: example2
emp_num: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
SELECT e.id_num
FROM example1 e, 
     example2 b 
WHERE e.id_num = b.emp_num
GROUP BY e.id_num
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql` tag on Oracle questions.

Comment: Why do you need a join in the first query? Just `SELECT ID_NUM, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE`.

Comment: In future please don't ask multiple questions in one post. StackOverflow is a Q&A site: the ideal thread has *one question* and one(accepted) answer to that question. Asking questions is free, so you don't need to bunch them up.

Comment: My apologies! I won't do that next time!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, as @Barmar said, you don't need a `join` at all, `SELECT ID_NUM, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE` will return what you need.

However, if for any other reason you need to join the table with itself, you have to do that on columns of the same type; the error you get is because `ID_NUM` is a number and `NAME` is text, so they are not comparable. This instead would be semantically correct

```
SELECT  e.ID_NUM as "ID NUMBER",
        b.NAME as "Name"
FROM    EMPLOYEE E
JOIN    EMPLOYEE B
ON      E.ID_NUM = B.ID_NUM
```

About the second question, that way of writing joins is 30 year obsolete, the proper way of writing that is with the syntax you used before

```
SELECT  e.id_num
FROM    example1 e
JOIN    example2 b 
ON      e.id_num = b.emp_num
```

You don't even need the `GROUP BY` clause, because in your `SELECT` there is no aggregation function (like sum or count).

Answer (score 0):

> "I get an "invalid number" error."

You are comparing a numeric value with a string. When evaluating such a condition Oracle casts the string to a number. Oracle gives us the benefit of the doubt and assumes the string column contains a numeric value like `'1234'`. In your case it fails because `'lee'` is not a valid number, and neither is `'gary'`.

You can get around this by doing an explicit cast of the number column:

```
SELECT e.ID_NUM as "ID NUMBER", 
       b.NAME as "Name"
FROM EMPLOYEE E
JOIN EMPLOYEE B on to_char(E.ID_NUM) = B.NAME
```

Now you're comparing a string with  a string so you won't get a casting error. Of course you won't get rows either, because `'gary' != '1'`. Not sure what business rule you're trying to implement so I can't fix that for you.

> "how do I join foreign keys with different names but same values in 2 different tables?"

Use the ANSI 92 join syntax from your previous query. You don't need a GROUP BY because you're not aggregating anything. If you want to show the different names you'll need to give them aliases to distinguish them:

```
SELECT e.id_num,
       e.name as e_name, 
       b.name as b_name
FROM example1 e
     join example2 b 
     on  e.id_num = b.emp_num
```